# PHP XPath issue

Tags: php, xml, xpath

Having a real bugger of an Xpath issue. I am trying to match the nodes with a certain value.

Here is an example XML fragment.

http://pastie.org/private/xrjb2ncya8rdm8rckrjqg

I am trying to match a given MatchNumber node value to see if there are two or more. Assuming that this is stored in a variable called $data I am using the below expression. Its been a while since ive done much XPath as most thing seem to be JSON these days so please excuse any rookie oversights.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->load($data);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$result = $xpath->query("/CupRoundSpot/MatchNumber[.='1']");
```

I need to basically match any node that has a Match Number value of 1 and then determine if the result length is greater than 1 ( i.e. 2 or more have been found ).

Many thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your XML document has a default namespace: `xmlns="http://www.fixtureslive.com/"`.
You have to [register this namespace](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/domxpath.registernamespace.php) on the xpath element and use the (registered) prefix in your query.

```
$xpath->registerNamespace ('fl' , 'http://www.fixtureslive.com/');
$result = $xpath->query("/fl:ArrayOfCupRoundSpot/fl:CupRoundSpot/fl:MatchNumber[.='1']");
foreach( $result as $e ) {
    echo '.';   
}
```

Comment: Cheers. I have tried running that but still get no matches / results. Very frustrating!

Comment: $doc->loadXML($data); was the issue what a tool! Cheers guys!

Answer (score 0):

The following XPath:

```
/CupRoundSpot[MatchNumber = 1]
```

Returns all the `CupRoundSpot` nodes where `MatchNumber` equals 1. You could use these nodes futher in your PHP to do stuff with it.

Executing:

```
count(/CupRoundSpot[MatchNumber = 1])
```

Returns you the total `CupRoundSpot` nodes found where `MatchNumber` equals 1.

Comment: Cheers. I have tried running that but still get no matches / results. Very frustrating!

Answer (score 0):

You have to register the namespace. After that you can use the Xpath `count()` function. An expression like that will only work with `evaluate()`, not with `query()`. `query()` can only return node lists, not scalar values.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$xpath->registerNamespace('fl', 'http://www.fixtureslive.com/');

var_dump(
  $xpath->evaluate(
    'count(/fl:ArrayOfCupRoundSpot/fl:CupRoundSpot[number(fl:MatchNumber) = 1])'
  )
);
```

Output:

```
float(2)
```

DEMO: https://eval.in/130366

To iterate the CupRoundSpot nodes, just use foreach:

```
$nodes = $xpath->evaluate(
  '/fl:ArrayOfCupRoundSpot/fl:CupRoundSpot[number(fl:MatchNumber) = 1]'
);
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
  //...
}
```